# Change social icon in twenty twenty three theme

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

I am trying to replace some of the default social icons with custom icons. Does anyone know how to change the svg icons for the Social Icons block in the Twenty Twenty Three theme? I don’t see the same class directory like twenty twenty one or two.